# How do I overcome build-time errors due to relative paths and custom imports with Next.JS applications?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js

This question has been answered in response in the context of Python, PHP, etc., but I cannot find an answer specific to this Next.JS blog I am creating. Each time I build, I get the following error from nodemon:

```
These dependencies were not found:

* /api/posts in ./pages/index.js
* /components/Post in ./pages/index.js
* /layouts/Main in ./pages/index.js
* /routes in ./pages/index.js
```

As you can see from the screen grab of my project folder, all the custom dependencies thread from my project folder.

[image: Project folder with relevant dependencies highlighted.]

My package.json file looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "revised-tottm",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "revised TOTTM website",
    "main": "_document.js",
    "dependencies": {
        "next": "^7.0.2",
        "next-routes": "^1.4.2",
        "nodemailer": "^4.7.0",
        "react": "^16.6.3",
        "react-dom": "^16.6.3",
        "reactdom": "^2.0.0",
        "static-server": "^2.2.1",
        "styled-components": "^4.1.2",
        "absolute-imports": "^1.0.1",
        "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
        "express": "^4.16.2",
        "get-form-data": "^2.0.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "babel-preset-env": "^1.5.2",
        "babel-preset-react": "6.24.1",
        "gulp": "^3.9.1",
        "gulp-babel": "^8.0.0",
        "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
        "gulp-imagemin": "^5.0.3",
        "gulp-livereload": "^4.0.1",
        "gulp-uglify": "^3.0.1",
        "gulp-uglify-es": "^1.0.4",
        "imagemin-jpeg-recompress": "^5.1.0",
        "imagemin-pngquant": "^6.0.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
        "dev": "next",
        "build": "next build",
        "start": "next start"
    },
    "author": "Joel J. Warne",
    "license": "ISC"
}
```

And I have tried variants, e.g. "require('./api/posts')" and "require('api/posts/')" but nothing seems to find them. For instance, if I change the paths to "require('./api/posts/')" and use a Next.JS "build" script, I get the following error:

```
> Failed to build

{ Error: (client) ./pages/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './api/posts' in '/Users/USERNAME/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/WebDevStudio/Revised TOTTM/pages'
 @ ./pages/index.js 10:0-39 37:19-27
 @ multi ./pages/index.js
    at /Users/USERNAME/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/WebDevStudio/Revised TOTTM/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:144:31
```

The entry point is correct, the project folder structure is correct, etc., but there is no reason that it should not be able to locate, for instance, '/api/posts/' that I can see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm curios if you are importing the modules propertly

For example:

If you want import `components/Post` into `pages/index.js` this should looks like this: `import Post from '../components/Post';`

Let me know if this works,

Regards

Comment: Yea, that worked. But should that be interpreted as meaning that you cannot travel from the project root to the component when importing custom components?

Comment: Hmm not really, if want to access from the root path I imagine you have to use `fs` package or so, but that doesn't make sense :). Good luck with your app, NexJS is awesome!